# Error con MongoDB no se crean mi BD

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Hola amigos tengo un error, resulta que tengo instalado mongoDB y anteriormente cuando creaba un servidor con node y creaba el Schema de la BD esta creaba normalmente pero ahora node no me crea la base de datos pero me dice conectado

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const { mongoose } = require('./database');

const app = express();

//configuraciones
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
//Rutas

app.use('/api/restaurante', require('./routes/restaurante.routes'));

//Archivos staticos
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//Incializar servidor



app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server en el puerto ${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

database.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/restaurante', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
})
.then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));


module.exports = mongoose;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La bd supuestamente conecta Pero cuando miro mis colleciones y bases de datos no aparece la BD restaurante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probe otros poryectos que tenia y funcionaban normalmente pero estos ya no funcionan tampoco tienen el mismo error: Lo que me sale en mongod es esto connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}

Comment: Agrega el puerto a tu cadena de conexión, en vez de esto: `'mongodb://localhost/restaurante'`, deberías tener esto otro: `'mongodb://localhost:27017/restaurante'`. Comenta el resultado. Saludos